# web page folder inside war in google app engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on Restful Web application. I am maintaining different project for web client code and Google app engine server code.

When ever i made changes in the client code, i rebuilt the client code and places inside the war folder of server project through build scripts.

Here i dont want to place all files directly to war folder and i wanted to put them under folder called 'Publish' for better maintainence. How can do it?

Is there any better way to maintaining client code and Google app engine server code?

The structure also works well for Mobile application in future.

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to this too, but there is versioning.  If you change the version number in your project manifest file, it does not become the default (i.e., visible to your original public URL).  It is public and accessible for you to test.  When you are ready to "publish" just switch the new version to be the default.  Use the *Manage* section of the Dashboard and set the *Version* to be the default when you are ready.

To test any of the earlier versions, you access through the *Manage* and click on the specific version.  I don't know if the persistent storage is versioned with this same mechanism -- I can image problems if you have a huge DB.